# Character array doesnt conform to new size

Tags: c++, arrays, strlen

I cannot figure out how to solve this problem. Its about reading a string from a file - row by row - then put every row in a new bigger characterarray. The problem here is that the latter characterarray (newStr) only takes the first row from the textfile - IF one looks att the stringlenght of the new file. But i Tried to loop beyond the arrays lenght and guess what? - Yes - here I found the chars from the second row.

So - what did I do wrong or miss? Why is the strlen(newStr) not conforming to the new bigger string?

```
void read3() {

   const char* FILE_NAME = "myfile2.txt";
   std::ifstream infil;
   infil.open(FILE_NAME);

   char ch[25];
   char newStr[200];

   for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
       newStr[i] = 0;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
       ch[i] = 0;
   }

   int pos = 0;
   while (infil.getline(ch, 25)) {
       unsigned int i;
       for (i = 0; i <= strlen(ch); i++) {
           newStr[pos + i] = ch[i];
       }
       pos += i;
   }

   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(newStr); i++) {
       std::cout << newStr[i];
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;

   // a second print of newStr beyond the loop to see if there are characters
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(newStr) + 24; i++) {
       std::cout << newStr[i];
   }

   std::cout << "\nlength of newStr: " << strlen(newStr);

}

int main() {

  read3();

return 0;
}
```

this is the contents of the textfile

```
 I am a row in notepad
 I am the second row :-)
```

Here is whats printed from the consolewindow

*1. if looping within the bounds*

```
  I am a row in notepad
```

*2. If looping beyond the bounds*

```
  I am a row in notepad[]I am the second row :-)
```

Comment: Every time you check the loop condition, you recompute strlen (from the beginning), which is unnecessary work. Compute it one and save the result to a temporary variable.

Comment: Why are you even using C strings in C++ code ?

Comment: @PaulR - you mean I should be using std::string instead?

Comment: Of course - if you want to learn C++ properly and get all the benefits then you should stick to C++ idioms.

Comment: @pts - but isn't the length of char ch different from time to time in the loop?

Comment: @user2365568: No, it isn't. Save it to a temporary variable just above each loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= strlen(ch); i++) {
```

write this:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(ch); i++) {
```

With `<=` it also copies the `\0`, which makes `strlen(newStr)` return only the length of the first line (because there is `\0` after the first line).

Answer (score 0):

I think that strlen(newStr) return the number of characters till the first \0. So you get only the first line till the first \0.